# put progressbar in recycle view android

Tags: java, android

how to put progressbar in recycleview?
i have to display progress bar when user play song in list,please help me.currently when user select any song ,user still wait for play the song.
thank you.
here is my code:

```
public class CustomAdapterNew extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapterNew.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<SlockDataModel> dataSet;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    Boolean check = false;


    private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";
    int current = -1;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title;
        ImageView img_play;
        AVLoadingIndicatorView progress;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_slock);
            this.img_play = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_play);
            progress = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.avi);

            itemView.setTag(this);
        }
    }

    public CustomAdapterNew(Context slock, ArrayList<SlockDataModel> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.slock_list_items, parent, false);
        final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
        final View mainView = holder.itemView;
        TextView title = holder.title;
        final ImageView btn_play = holder.img_play;
        title.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getValue());
        title.setTag(listPosition);

        if(listPosition != current){
            btn_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play_btn);
        } else {
            btn_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.stop_btn);
        }

        title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SlockNew.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String str = dataSet.get(listPosition).getSong();
                v.getTag(listPosition);
                View oldSongView = SlockNew.lv.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(current);

                if (!check || current != listPosition) {
                    if (current != -1) {
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        btn_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.stop_btn);
                        ((ImageView) oldSongView.findViewById(R.id.img_play)).setImageResource(R.mipmap.play_btn);
                    }
                    playsong(str);
                    btn_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.stop_btn);
                    check = true;
                    current = listPosition;
                    SlockNew.progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                } else {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                    }
                    check = false;
                    Log.i(TAG, "ELSE");
                    btn_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play_btn);
                    current = -1;
                    SlockNew.progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
            //Tapan
            private void playsong(String str) {
                String url = str;
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
   if(listPosition != current){
        btn_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play_btn);
        holder.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btn_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.stop_btn);
        holder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```